# Water animation in Maya, Blend or XNA

Tags: c#, wpf, xna, blender, maya

I need to make a water fountain animation. But I'm not a designer, I'm developer. At first I denied such task. But Is quite interesting and I'd love to open and broad my skills. Please avoid answering "you should say no".

So I started research to accomplish this task.

The main goal is to render a water fountain, on which I can change the color of the water, and the height of the stream.
. 
My first thought was WPF. So I've found a few examples, some of them uses shader. And there is one interesting, [Simple Water Animation](http://stuff.seans.com/2008/08/21/simple-water-animation-in-wpf/). I liked this one because it runs smootly. But it doesn't reach the quality I need. So, the research continued.

Then, with a youtube search, (yep, google is google, but youtube also works ;) ) I found 3 good resources. Maya, Blender and XNA.

Maya and Blender: These are a whole new world for me. I know I can learn these suites. But my concern is about the functionality I need at this moment. Actually, my company own a license for Maya, thats why it is in the list.

In the past, I've tried to do something alike, sending parameters from C# to a SWF movie embedded in the winform. Result.. failiure. Using external interface class in actionscript, well, it work, but not as I wanted, so I moved to WPF.

I really don't want this happen again, with Maya or Blender.

The functionality I need is to send params to the animation. Is this possible with Maya or Blender. And, the animation will run in a window or can be embedded in the WinForm? Or, another approach, a text file where I put the params, and the animation loads it at startup.

XNA: This one is quite interesting too, and is NET! And after looking at the code of some examples. Ahh! I don't get it! Ive seen a few which render water, and are awesome. But I haven't found a picture example or video with a fountain or a water stream. So, might be easier to learn, it also requires time but less than the other options.

After all this, I'm still confused and looking for more information. The options are:

1)Maya

2)Blender

3)XNA

Have anyone done something like this before?
Which will you take in my position?
Which path is the best way to accomplish my task?

I'm not asking for a piece of code with the solution like many questions in this site. I'm looking for direction, based on experience or knowledge.

I'd like something like: -"use 'this' tecnology, it has a function/component which you can use to do 'that', heres a link to an example/documentation".

But is not always that easy. So any suggestion will be very, very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is the solution I have take.

Maya and Blender are really good suites, very powerfull. But, as far as I read, once an animation is rendered, there is no change. If I need to make a change, I have to render it again. So Maya and Blender are discarded.

Then, XNA. This framework is amazing. But is complex. I've read a lot, and still can't create a terrain. Maybe just need more time, but time is running out. But, I'm still reading about this framework as an alternative, and thanks to @SuperPrograman, the DPSF is a good asset.

So, what was the solution: Unity3D.

Is nice tool. It has a particle emmiter and with [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6fdhFoUXNI), I made a fountain. Also, you can create scripts in javascript or c# with Mono. So now I'm at the stage of create a script to edit the properties of the particle emmiter to control my fountain. And there's a lot of documentation and support forums.

Hope this helps someone too.

Regards.

Comment: Yeah, should have thought of that. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Blender a little, and I don't think that you will be able to send params to the fountain animation, *unless* you incorporate python code (blender is coded in python). All I have ever done with blender is make an animation, render it as a movie file and that is how the animation is, no changing  unless you re-render. So I don't think Blender will work. Maya would probably have similar problems.

Personally I think that XNA (or something like it) is probably the best way to go. One link for XNA that I found that I think might be useful, is [here](http://www.xnaparticles.com/). Basically, it is some sort of API; the first thing it says on the site, that describes it quite well is,

> DPSF (Dynamic Particle System Framework) is a tried and tested, free programmer's tool for creating custom particle systems in XNA quickly and easily.

One example of it being used for a fountain is found on youtube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWP0zDkt-BM). Yeah, that video is pretty cheesy, but it could probably be made better.

Or you could just try using [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10003/A-basic-Particles-System) to create a C# only fountain.

Yet again you could use as you first thought WPF with 3d. Ha Ha. All I came up with there was [this](http://www.mperfect.net/wpf3dPart/) for a fountain. I'll keep looking and edit if I come up with anything better. I admit, my links aren't all that great.

+1 on question!